# CRAM-based control system - what to start from

Tags: ros, cram, knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, everyone!
I participate in one robotics project at my University. it is development of high-level control system for full-sized humanoid robot. It will be used to manipulate objects and to navigate in office-like environment (e.g. his task could be "find a blue ball on a table and bring it to me"). I want to use CRAM for this. I've studied some papers about CRAM and KnowRob, walked through tutorials, I understand main principles and architecture of CRAM. but what now? What should I start from? my colleagues are currently writing initial ros package to abstract low-level mechanisms.
Can anyone provide an example of CRAM-based control system?
Should I first fill in the knowledge base with needed data (furniture, room description etc.) or should I write some simple plans?

any help is appreciated..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59925/cram-based-control-system---what-to-start-from/) by [johnkorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4603/johnkorn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Probably you already know the tutorials at http://www.ros.org/wiki/cram_core/Tutorials.
There are some more advanced examples by the authors of CRAM in their GitHub repository, see e.g. https://github.com/cram-code/cram_pr2.git.

I would start out by writing some simple CRAM plans without KnowRob at first to get used to the system. Later you can extend these to make use of KnowRob queries.

---

Originally posted by [ddimarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1073/ddimarco/) with karma: 916 on 2013-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [johnkorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4603/johnkorn/) on 2013-04-14**:
Thank you, ddimarco. That link you provided was really helpfull. main thing that i realized is that there is a lot of hard and very interesting work ahead!))